# pamac fails with "Failed to create the directory $BUILDDIR" but it already exists

Tags: linux, arch-linux, packages, manjaro

I'm facing a really weird issue in Manjaro when trying to install packages from the AUR:

```sh
$ pamac build vorta
[...]
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ====

Building vorta...
==> Making package: vorta 0.8.12-1 (Sun Jun 18 14:38:30 2023)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
[...]
==> Removing existing $pkgdir/ directory...
==> Starting build()...
[...]
==> Entering fakeroot environment...
==> ERROR: Failed to create the directory $BUILDDIR (/var/tmp/pamac-build-felix/vorta).
    Aborting...
```

I found [a single source on the entirety of google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%20%22entering%20fakeroot%20environment%22%20%22failed%20to%20create%20the%20directory%22&ei=jveOZPKWBoTbkgWPioCwDw&ved=0ahUKEwjylZCH6Mz_AhWEraQKHQ8FAPYQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=%20%22entering%20fakeroot%20environment%22%20%22failed%20to%20create%20the%20directory%22&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQA0oECEEYAVDPAVjPAWDOA2gCcAB4AIABPIgBPJIBATGYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) for my exact issue; [a 1 year old reddit post with no resolution](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/t3j2ei/). There's also an [old post on stackoverflow about permission issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50768907/makepkg-error-failed-to-create-the-directory-builddir) causing a similar error, but the answers don't fix my problem and the permissions on my directory were already fine. Anything else I found is similar to that, where the build fails even before `build()` is ever called, but in my case it fails while entering the fakeroot environment.

*How can I get to the bottom of this?*

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to note is that pamac is mostly just a wrapper around a few other programs, most notably pamac, yay and makepkg. In this case, [makepkg](https://gitlab.archlinux.org/pacman/pacman/-/tree/master/scripts) is the lowest part of the stack, and it's mostly just a bash script.  This makes it very easy to see what's going on. We can just call makepkg directly in the directory created when we called pamac first:

```sh
$ cd /var/tmp/pamac-build-felix/vorta
$ makepkg
==> Making package: vorta 0.8.12-1 (Sun Jun 18 14:38:30 2023)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
[...]
==> Removing existing $pkgdir/ directory...
==> Starting build()...
[...]
==> Entering fakeroot environment...
==> ERROR: Failed to create the directory $BUILDDIR (/var/tmp/pamac-build-felix/vorta).
    Aborting...
```

We get pretty much the same output as before. Now, let's have a look at what makepkg actually does:

```sh
$ which makepkg
$ vim /usr/bin/makepkg # Or use less or any other editor
```

Searching for `fakeroot`, we find this function:

```sh
enter_fakeroot() {
        msg "$(gettext "Entering %s environment...")" "fakeroot"
        fakeroot -- bash -$- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" -F "${ARGLIST[@]}" || exit $?
}
```

It is only called two times. Those calls are mutually exclusive and they happen near the end of the program, so this is one of the last things that happens when building an AUR package.

So how about just trying to run fakeroot? We don't know what all the other arguments do, but let's just use one and see what happens:

```sh
$ fakeroot -- bash
date: /nix/store/q29bwjibv9gi9n86203s38n0577w09sx-glibc-2.33-117/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /usr/lib/libfakeroot/libfakeroot.so)
```

**Aha! That doesn't look like normal behavior!**

But why would `date` be linking against the wrong glibc?

```sh
$ which date
/home/felix/.nix-profile/bin/date
```

And so here we have the culprit. Because all of these programs are scripts, they just call the versions of all the tools that are in the user environment. As I'm using Nix, all the tools in my user env are linked against a different glibc than those of the distribution. Usually, this isn't a problem, but **fakeroot is a clever hack** that can break down in this situation:

> **fakeroot** works by replacing the file manipulation library functions (chmod(2), stat(2) etc.) by ones that simulate the effect the real library functions would have had, had the user really been root. These wrapper functions are in a shared library **`/usr/lib/*/libfakeroot-*.so`** or similar location on your platform. The shared object is loaded through the **LD_PRELOAD** mechanism of the dynamic loader. (See ld.so(8))

[See `man fakeroot(1)`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/fakeroot.1.en)

On this particular machine, I hadn't updated my user environment in a long time, and so the calls to the tools in that environment (including `date`) were linked against the old glibc 2.33, while the version installed by manjaro was glibc 2.34. When running my tools normally, everything worked perfectly fine due to how Nix is defined. But when fakeroot forces these tools to load symbols from `/usr/lib/libfakeroot/libfakeroot.so` with `LD_PRELOAD`, the dynamic loading fails, as `libfakeroot.so` is linked against manjaro's version of glibc.

The solution was to update my channels and environment:

```sh
$ nix-channel --list
nixpkgs https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-22.05
$ nix-channel --add https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-unstable nixpkgs
$ nix-channel --update
unpacking channels...
$ nix-env -u
upgrading 'qmk-1.1.1' to 'qmk-1.1.2'
upgrading 'yt-dlp-2023.2.17' to 'yt-dlp-2023.3.4'
upgrading 'nil-2023-01-01' to 'nil-2023-05-09'
upgrading 'asdf-vm-0.9.0' to 'asdf-vm-0.11.3'
[...]
building '/nix/store/l8zpn4ccrmqzh0q9pzc543bhw3vfn10v-user-environment.drv'...
```

And now, fakeroot and thus makepkg and thus pamac succeeds:

```sh
[...]
==> Leaving fakeroot environment.
==> Finished making: vorta 0.8.12-1 (Sun Jun 18 15:46:41 2023)
==> Cleaning up...
[...]
Updating icon theme caches...                             [3/4]
Updating the desktop file MIME type cache...              [4/4]
Transaction successfully finished.
```